# How to get cart quote item id in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I tried,

```
 $items = $item->getQuote()->getAllItems();

 foreach($items as $item1)
 {
      $productId = $item1->getProductId();
      $itemId = $item1->getItemId();
 }
```

I am getting blank value.

Can anyone tell me how to call checkout_cart_add_product_complete event in observer ?

Comment: where you tried this code ?

Comment: try `$item1->getId();`

Comment: how to call checkout_cart_add_product_complete event in observer: 
 http://blog.briteskies.com/blog/an-introduction-to-events-in-magento-2

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala - I tried but first instance it wont give value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For call observer **checkout_cart_add_product_complete** you need to create a module and create event.xml file in frontend area

> etc/frontend/event.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_cart_add_product_complete">
         <observer name="test_callobserver" instance="Test\Callobserver\Observer\Cartitems"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

2) Now call **Cartitems** in path `Test\Callobserver\Observer\`

```
<?php
namespace Test\Callobserver\Observer;

use \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

use \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session as CheckoutSession;

class Cartitems implements ObserverInterface {

    /** @var CheckoutSession */
    protected $checkoutSession;

    /**
     * @param CheckoutSession $checkoutSession
     */
    public function __construct(CheckoutSession $checkoutSession) {
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer) {
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor $product */
        $product = $observer->getProduct();

        /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote  */
        $quote = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote(); //here you will get quote data
    }
}
```

This code help you.

Comment: How to update custom attribute in given quote item table

Comment: First You need to find $quoteItem from above code then simply set custom attribute with code $quoteItem->setCustomAttribute($product->getCustomAttribute());