# Change product price in cart each page loaded with observer

Tags: magento2, php, event-observer

I tried to update the price of each product in cart each time I load a page. I used observer and event `catalog_product_collection_load_after`. I tried to get each item in the cart from observer but its always null if I do var_dump for it. Am I doing it wrong?

Observer :

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
     $quoteItem = $observer->getQuoteItem();
     var_dump($quoteItem); //always NULL
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That event observer stores only collection data:

```
$collection = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();
foreach ($collection as $product) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try Code:

<?php
namespace Test\Callobserver\Observer;

use \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

use \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session as CheckoutSession;

class Cartitems implements ObserverInterface {

    /** @var CheckoutSession */
    protected $checkoutSession;

    /**
     * @param CheckoutSession $checkoutSession
     */
    public function __construct(CheckoutSession $checkoutSession) {
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer) {
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor $product */
        $product = $observer->getProduct();

        /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote  */
        $quote = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote(); //here you will get quote data
    }
}        


    Reference Link:
    https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/192846/24878
```

Comment: you sure it could works on "catalog_product_collection_load_after" event?

Comment: if you want change cart item attribute  then why use catalog_product_collection_load_after ?,you should try as per link.

Comment: i want to update price of each product in cart each time page is loaded, because i tried use on fly data, so if in my data the price updated, i should update the price on the cart too